# What do you call the person who performs an action?

Tags: grammar, terminology

What do you call the person who does the verb? For instance, in the sentence

> John killed Frank

what is the grammatical term for *John*?

I don't know if "agent" is the right word?

Comment: The *verber*?  The *doer*?  What are you actually asking here?

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Hazel. I have *guessed* at what I think you are asking, and have edited your question accordingly; if this is not what you meant, please rollback my edit and clarify what it is you are looking for.

Comment: Please edit the question to include references cited and your own research results. Questions lacking evidence of research effort are incomplete.

Comment: John is the *killer*.

Answer (score 14):

I take it that you are asking for a technical term used in the formal linguistic study of grammar.

Within that domain, the questions you ask in the title and in the body of your question are really two different questions, and require two different actions. Permit me to rephrase a little.

***What do you call the person who ‘does’ the verb [in a sentence]?***
This is a *syntactic* entity and is called the **subject** of the verb or sentence.

***What do you call the person who performs [the] action [expressed in the verb]?***
This is a *semantic* entity and is called the **Agent** of the sentence or proposition.

It is important to distinguish these two entities, because in some sentences they may be *different* persons (or animals or institutions or in fact any noun or noun phrase – they need not be *persons*).

In the sentence “John killed Frank”, for instance, *John* is both the **subject** of the verb *kill* and the **Agent** of the action the verb expresses. (*Frank*, by the way, is the *direct object* of the verb and the *Patient* of the action it expresses.)

But if you recast the same sentence into the passive voice, “Frank was killed by John”, *Frank*  (which was the *direct object* in the previous sentence) becomes the **subject** of the verb—but *John* is still the **Agent** of the action.

Comment: I think I understand the question better now

Comment: @Ian   Well, it's a guess on my part what OP is looking for.

Comment: I know what you mean. It's only the first post, so it's OK :)

Comment: What theta role would you suggest for the subject _John_ in the deponent structure _John was born_?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If I regarded it as a true deponent I would have to say *John* is the Impatient :)

Comment: One day I'll learn how to vote on this site. Then comes the even more difficult problem of deciding which way.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answers have covered the question in terms of traditional grammar, but another way of looking at language is from the perspective of functional grammar. It’s a complex subject, but this is how functional grammar would analyze your example.

Functional grammar sees a clause as centred on a **Process**, realised as a verb. Processes can be of several kinds, but the one we perhaps come across most often is the **Material Process**, that is, something that happens in the real world. In the example, *killed* is just such a Material Process. The persons and things that initiate a Process and that may be on its receiving end are called **Participants**. Where the Process is a Material Process, the initiating Participant is known as the **Actor**, and the Participant being acted upon is known as the **Goal**. So, in the example, *John* is the Actor and *Frank* is the Goal.

As StoneyB has pointed out, making the clause passive doesn’t change the fact that it was John who did the killing. Functional grammar recognises this in that in the passive clause *Frank was killed by John*, *John* is still the Actor, and *Frank* is still the Goal.

Comment: +1 Back in the 1940s Kenneth Burke employed something very similar for rhetorical analysis of ideologies, what he called a "dramatistic" *Grammar of Motives* whose key terms were Act, Actor, Agency, Scene, Purpose. I've often thought it would be interesting to try developing that into a linguistic grammar.

Comment: @StoneyB. I didn’t know about Burke. The best known proponent of functional grammar is Michael Halliday, following the work of Malinowski and Firth. I’ve attempted a brief and superficial summary here: http://realgrammar.posterous.com/functional-grammar

Comment: Halliday and functional grammar are coming up everywhere I look; I guess I'm going to have to burn a few months learning this. Not least because he expresses himself with English rather than Latin terminology!

Comment: @StoneyB. As I say in my piece, functional grammar hasn't really entered the lingustics mainstream in the UK or US. If you want an introduction, the one I mention is as good as any. Once you get into it, you may find you prefer Latin terminology.

Answer (score 1):

The noun (person, place or thing) that performs the action directed by the verb is the ***subject*** of the sentence. For example:

> **John** walks.

**John** is the subject and **walks** is the verb.

If you mean the noun that the verb is done to, then it's the ***direct object***. For example:

> John walks **the dog**.

**The dog** is the direct object.

Answer (score 0):

The subject, I suppose.  You know, the subject performs
the action contained in the verb.  Example:  The cat [subject]
chased [verb] the mouse.